# Why does DirectXToolkit ruin my depth testing

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, depth-testing, directxtk

I'm sure I'm just missing some simple step that I've been too blind to notice so far, but I cannot seem to get depth testing to work at all. This is with DirectX 11.

The code that should set it all up:

```cpp
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapDesc = { };
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 0;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 0;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;

    swapDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    swapDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    swapDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
    swapDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    swapDesc.Flags = 0;

    UINT flg = 0;
#if MAGE_DEBUG
    flg |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    GFX_THROW_INFO(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
        flg,
        nullptr, 0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapDesc, &mSwap, &mDevice, nullptr,
        &mContext));

    COMptr<ID3D11Resource> backBuffer;
    GFX_THROW_INFO(mSwap->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), &backBuffer));
    GFX_THROW_INFO(mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer.Get(), nullptr, &mTarget));


    LOG_INFO("Setting depth stencil dimensions ({}, {})", width, height);
    COMptr<ID3D11Texture2D> depthStencil;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc = { };
    texDesc.Width = width;
    texDesc.Height = height;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    GFX_THROW_INFO(mDevice->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, nullptr, &depthStencil));

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depth = { };
    depth.DepthEnable = TRUE;
    depth.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depth.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;


    COMptr<ID3D11DepthStencilState> depthState;
    GFX_THROW_INFO(mDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&depth, &depthState));


    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc = { };
    dsvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    dsvDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    GFX_THROW_INFO(mDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencil.Get(), &dsvDesc, &mDepthStencilView));

    mContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthState.Get(), 1);
    mContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, mTarget.GetAddressOf(), mDepthStencilView.Get());

    LOG_INFO("Setting viewport dimensions ({}, {})", width, height);
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (float) width;
    vp.Height = (float) height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
    mContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
```

And of course, before every frame I call the following:

```
    mContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mTarget.Get(), color);
    mContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView.Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
```

But unfortunately, the result ends up being this (note that the crysis nanosuit model is behind the goblin head) I believe this could potentially also be why the goblin model is rendering incorrectly even when alone but haven't figured that one out yet.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6THhz.jpg)

And with just the goblin, looking from an angle

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNUkl.jpg)

If anyone can help me figure out why its not working, I'd greatly appreciate it!

## EDIT

After some more frustrating testing I discovered the depth testing was broken because of some test text rendering I was doing with DirectX ToolKit's SpriteBatch and SpriteFont classes. Has anyone come across this issue before? I don't really want/need the toolkit for anything other than text rendering and perhaps loading dds textures so I'm hoping if I want to use those classes I don't need to drastically change my existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DirectX Tool Kit* does not 'capture/restore' state like the legacy D3DX9/D3DX10 sprite did. This was inefficient and relied on some hacky back-door functionality to capture the 'state block' for Direct3D 10+. In most cases, you are already going to set the bulk of the commonly used state to set up for the next draw call anyhow.

Instead, I have fully documented all state impacted by each class. You are expected to change all required state *after* the *DirectX Tool Kit* object renders. For example, [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch) docs state:

> `SpriteBatch` makes use of the following states:
>
> - BlendState
> - Constant buffer (Vertex Shader stage, slot 0)
> - DepthStencilState
> - Index buffer
> - Input layout
> - Pixel shader
> - Primitive topology
> - RasterizerState
> - SamplerState (Pixel Shader stage, slot 0)
> - Shader resources (Pixel Shader stage, slot 0)
> - Vertex buffer (slot 0)
> - Vertex shader

So in short, you just need to set the DepthStencilState to what you want to use after you call `SpriteBatch::End`.

> As a general habit for state management, you should set all state you rely on every frame. While in Direct3D 11 the 'last state' at the time you call `Present` is still there at the start of the next frame, this isn't true of DirectX 12. As such, you should make a habit of at the start of a new frame setting everything like current render target,  viewport, render states you expect to be present for your whole scene, etc.

> For example, most "HUD" rendering is done last, so the state changes by SpriteBatch would normally be reset on the next frame's start--again, assuming you set up the required state at the start of the frame rather than assuming it remains unchanged over many frames.

**TL;DR:** Move this code to just after you clear the render target each frame:

```
    mContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthState.Get(), 1);
    mContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, mTarget.GetAddressOf(), mDepthStencilView.Get());

    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp = { 0.f, 0.f, float(width), float(height), D3D11_MIN_DEPTH, D3D11_MAX_DEPTH };
    mContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything seems to be working now after adding `RSSetViewports`, `OMSetDepthStencilState`, and `OMSetRenderTargets` before each frame